Is Patrick Drevet considered difficult reading in French?
I picked up a novel of Patrick Drevet’s recently (« Le Visiteur de Hasard », Éditions Gallimard, 1987), thinking I would enjoy it, based on a brief bio of the author I had chanced upon. But I am having so much trouble sorting out his syntax and vocabulary, I am tempted to put it down and try something else.
Example: « Avec une acuité qui s'emoussera au fil des jours, tous les regards convergent encore vers le professeur, les visages s'oublient dans un affût qui l'enserre et le détaille, les cœurs sont retenus à ses paroles et se laissent toucher, le temps qu'affleurent à la conscience les sentiments qu'il y suscite, par le timbre de sa voix. »
That is just one of several equally long, complicated sentences I encountered on the first two pages, and spent some time laboriously sorting out.
Can anyone recommend a more accessible introduction to Drevet? Or am I likely to find all of his writing too complex?
I would describe my reading level as intermediate, but I had far less trouble with Camus and Flaubert than I am having with this.

Any answer will be subjective, it much depends on one's own grasp of French (even for French natives) and interest in the subject matter (childhood, expression of feelings...). P. D. is known for his very specific style (numerous academic reviews have been written). He has taken part in a French translation of Joyce's Ulysses (not that I compare his style with Joyce's but to show what kind of style he deals with. With Devret the reader has to confront style and abstract complex ideas.

Here's an extract from a review in the paper Le Monde : "Chacun de ses romans est un combat avec l'impossible : la description infinie des sensations de l'instant, de l'ivresse du désir, de l'enchantement des sens. Désirs que la société rend plus ou moins licites, désirs volés à l'indifférence dominante, désirs arrachés à l'oubli. Le Visiteur de hasard, notamment, était un réquisitoire contre les préjugés étouffants de la médiocrité." and from another: "raffinement dans les analogies [...] glissements de sens et des sens [...] exactitude dans le désir de voir..."

I am tempted to put it down and try something else. Yield to temptation by all means: at intermediate reading level you want to improve, and this will happen whenever the act of reading is a pleasant experience in itself. Your post reads like just now, reading Devret is not. Chances are, this will change when you have enjoyed many, many authors whose style you relate to, so that you had fun overcoming the grammatical challenges they pose to foreigners. Poets, playwrights, philosophers, scientists, polemists, you name it.

Thanks for your helpful comments, "None" and François Jurain. You help me understand what I’m in for if I continue with this book. And I think I will, as I find your comments on the whole encouraging. Forewarned is forearmed, as they say.
Thanks in particular for pointing me to sources like Le Monde’s review. I have already encountered some of that infinite description of sensations and shifts in meaning, and now know to expect those.

Yes, it looks like Drevet's literary style is considered rich and complex.
From an article in Le Monde:

Patrick Drevet est armé : d'un style, déjà reconnu et analysé par de
nombreux universitaires, unique par sa précision, par les volutes de
sa syntaxe, par son rythme lancinant

Random comments about one of his books:

une écriture magnifiquement maîtrisée, tout en finesse, en subtilité, en nuances, d'une grande richesse de vocabulaire


j'ai dû le lire de la main gauche, pendant que la droite cherchait les mots dans le dictionnaire

According to some commentators, he would even drown the reader in obscure mannerisms on purpose to inspire a poetic trip:

« En équilibre sur les vergues, il accordait ses gestes à ceux des
matelots pour ferler de concert la misaine, le grand perroquet ou le
hunier d’artimon, repliant la voile ris par ris au moyen des garcettes
pour diminuer la surface exposée au vent, ou au contraire, les
larguant. » (p. 16).
Voici, puisée au hasard, un autre échantillon du
style maniéré de l’auteur, qui tisse son roman comme une grille de
mots croisés force 5 [4]. Ces termes techniques que nous ignorons
constituent des « asémantèmes » (signifiants que le lecteur lambda est
incapable d’associer à aucun référent).

I'm not sure his earlier books are any less complex, but you could always try if they are available.

Thanks for your response, guillaume31, and the citations you offer. I might argue with “unique par sa précision”, unless “précision” can also mean deliberate obfuscation. But, yes, there are definitely “volutes de syntaxe” here, and I am going to try to enjoy deciphering them, while at the same time doing my best to appreciate “son rythme lancinant.”

Syntax is definitely more of a problem than vocabulary in this book. I have not yet encountered specialized language like the nautical terms in one of the examples you cite. I am looking up a fair number of words, but that’s not too troubling. More difficult is deciphering point of view. The author is inside the head of his main character, a teacher, but the teacher is sometimes inside the heads of his students, and the shift can happen from one phrase to the next within the same sentence.

Knowing that the author is known for mastery, finesse, subtlety, nuance, and richness of language encourages me to soldier on, and see how much of those things I can appreciate in this book.
